# cURL request is getting NULL response from imgur api

Tags: php, api, curl, xampp, imgur

```
    $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
    $id = 'myid';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Client-ID ' . $id));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'image' => base64_encode($image) ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response);
```

this is the block of quote that i have to make anonymous image uploads to imgur. it works on xampp on my mac os machine, but it is not working on xampp on my windows. i also know the following about curl on windows xampp:

```
-it is enabled
-it works when i try to grab the content of an url
-it doesnt work when i try to make DELETE request to remove an anonymous image(the same code works on the mac os xampp)
```

i figured there are some differences between the cURL settings on the two computers. i would appreciate it if you can show me the ways! thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look in your `phpinfo()`, there is a section called "curl". Try comparing those.

Comment: See what cURL errors are being outputted `echo curl_error();` It could be a problem with the CA and then in that case you need to point to it with the correct cURL function.

Comment: Horribly shameless plug: you can use Runscope to inspect the request/response data without having to dump out the response in your code. That way you can see what the actual API response is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an SSL issue. Please try the following line before the `curl_exec` call

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

(And you might add `var_dump($response);` to see the server response.)

Comment: do i accept by upvote the answer? sorry, this was my first question, and i dont have enough rep to upvote the answer yet. however, i promise i'll come back to it when i can.

Comment: The check mark should be under the vote buttons.. like so http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png